# Calculation of limits with $\alpha_k,2^{\alpha_k}$ on $\left\{\alpha_{k}\in N\ \ |\ \ k\in N: \sin\alpha_{k}>\sin\alpha_{k-1} \right\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let us consider a sequence:
$$
\left\{\alpha_{k}\in N\ \ |\ \  k\in N: \sin\alpha_{k}>\sin\alpha_{k-1} \right\}
$$
Calculate the following limits
$$
1)\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^{\alpha_k}}{2^{\alpha_{k+1}}}
$$
$$
2)\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\alpha_k}{\alpha_{k+1}}
$$
$$
3)\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{2^{\alpha_k}}{2^{\alpha_{k+1}}}\right) \left(\frac{\alpha_k}{\alpha_{k+1}}\right)
$$

Comment: $\lim_{k \to \infty }\sin(\alpha _{k})=\alpha $ which exists. So $0< \sin(\alpha _{k+1}) - \sin(\alpha _{k})=\cos(\varphi _{k})\cdot (\alpha _{k+1} -\alpha _{k})< \varepsilon $, where $\varphi _{k} \in (\alpha _{k}, \alpha _{k+1})$ ... no further progress though ...

Comment: and $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty }\cos(\varphi _{k})=0$

Answer (score 3):

There is nowhere nearly enough information. For example, in the first question, $\alpha_k= \pi/2-1/k$ is a possibility (whereupon the limit is $1.$) But $\alpha_k = \pi/2 -1/k + 2\pi k^2 $is another poossibility, whereupon the limit is $0,$ and $\alpha_k = \pi/2 -1/k -2\pi k^2$ yet another, when the limit is $\infty.$

Comment: I just modified the text and the title of my question!

Comment: @Lely It’s not clearer now

Comment: I think the condition that $\alpha_k\in\mathbb{N}$ may play a big role here. At least it does lead to $\lim_{k\to\infty} \alpha_k \to \infty$. However, I'm not sure how to proceed beyond that now.